# Is there a list of JSON parse error codes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm trying to provide a good experience to users that are using JSON and the parser is on the backend (Ruby).

Most of the time, when you get a badly formatted JSON payload the error is of the format `XXX unexpected token at '<entire payload here>'`. That's not very user-friendly nor practical.

My question is: Is there a list of the `XXX` error codes that could help create better error messages that could be understood by beginners and not-really-tech-people?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XXX` in this kind of errors is not a special code of the error. It is just a line number from the file where this error was raised. For example, for Ruby 2.5.1 you'll get `JSON::ParserError (765: unexpected token at` https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_5_1/ext/json/parser/parser.rl#L765

Comment: You're right. This means my question is not the good one, I'm looking for a way to inform the user of what is their typo. I'll mark your answer as the correct one. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. Check this question's answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014969/finding-json-errors-with-ruby

Comment: Oh indeed switching to MultiJson + Oj provides a much better error message. I knew Oj was fast but I didn't know it provided more accurate parsing errors ^^ Thanks!

Comment: I thought the same thing as OP that number looks like an error code. Putting the line number of the file the error is happening on seems useless. I wonder why that decision was made.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list in the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) for the module.

Think this covers it:

```
JSON::JSONError
JSON::GeneratorError
JSON::GenericObject
# The base exception for JSON errors.
JSON::MissingUnicodeSupport
# This exception is raised if the required unicode support is missing on the system. Usually this means that the iconv library is not installed.
JSON::NestingError
# This exception is raised if the nesting of parsed data structures is too deep.
JSON::ParserError
# This exception is raised if a parser error occurs.
JSON::UnparserError
# This exception is raised if a generator or unparser error occurs.
```

`JSON::JSONError` is the parent class, so you can rescue from that and provide per-error-class messages as needed.

I feel it's worth noting that in my experience the vast majority of errors relating to JSON are of the class `JSON::ParserError`. Another common issue worth considering is getting `ArgumentError` if `nil` is passed as an argument.

As an example of how this could be used, you could work with something like the following:

```
begin
  JSON.parse(your_json)
rescue JSON::JSONError, ArgumentError => e
  { error: I18n.t(e.to_s) } # <- or whatever you want to do per error
end
```

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Hi, thanks. My question was not explicit enough. I'm looking for a better granularity regarding the ParserError case because users know something is wrong but they don't know what.